# Why do we want probability spaces and filtrations to be complete?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

A probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is called complete iff every subset $\tilde{N}$ of a set $N$ of measure $0$ is measurable, i.e. if $\mathbb{P}(N) = 0$ and $\tilde{N} \subseteq N$ implies that $\tilde{N}\in \mathcal{A}$. Similarly, a filtration $(\mathcal{A}_t)_{t \in I}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is called complete iff, for all $t \in I$, the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}_t, \mathbb{P} )$ is complete.

I have noticed, that completness of the probability space and completeness of filtrations is a frequent assumption in various textbooks on stochastic calculus and Brownian motion. Why is this the case? What is the advantage if we only restrict ourselves to complete measure spaces and filtrations in the study of stochastic processes?

Kind regards,
Joker

Comment: There's no real 'restriction', since you can always 'complete' the space

Comment: I understand that, but why would I even bother to complete the space in the first place?

Comment: To change sets by subsets of sets of measure zero.

Comment: In which concrete scenario would this be necessary/relevant?